# Why did git keep the files after I changed back to master?

Tags: git

I was working in a branch that I created like:

```
git checkout -b feature_xyz
```

After working in that branch, I wanted to throw away all the work so I moved back to master:

```
git checkout master
```

When I did that, I saw this:

M  app/path/to/file1.rb
M  app/path/to/file2.rb
D  app/path/to/file3.rb
switched to branch 'master'
your branch is up-to-date with origin/master

I then deleted the feature branch:

```
git branch -d feature_xyz
```

Now when I do git status I see files that I was modifying in that feauture_xyz branch, how is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git is intended to work like this.  Uncommitted changes get carried from branch to branch as you switch, *if* they can be.

See [Git - checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452) for more information.

Comment: so next time as long as I commit then it is fine right? I mean that is what I have been doing w/o issue before.

Comment: Yes, once they are added-and-committed, Git knows you don't intend to carry the changed files around with every new `git checkout`.